# Fatal error: Call to undefined function TextStatusPurchase

Tags: php

I have a function called TextStatusPurchase that i want to call. For an instance I'm working on my page purchase_edit.php. Inside that page i have the following data Name, Date, Means of Payment, Total, Status of actual purchase, Books and all of them are in php. This is what im talking about. If i remove the TextStatusPurchase, it displays the status of the purchase as a 0. If put echo TextStatusPurchase after the Status of actual purchase it suppose to display 0= Waiting, 1= pay and send and 2= purchase cancel which i have created them in my function page. Instead of the 0 it should display Waiting but its not displaying anything but a fatal error:Call to undefined function

**Directory Structure:**
Site - bookstore
  *-admin*
    purchase_list.php,
    purchase_edit.php,
    index.php,
  *-includes*
    catalago.php,
    functions.php,
    headadmin.php,

**purchase_edit.php**

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/databaseConnection.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$varPurchase_Datapurchase = "0";
if (isset($_GET["recordID"])) {
  $varPurchase_Datapurchase = $_GET["recordID"];
}
mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
$query_Datapurchase = sprintf("SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE purchase.idpurchase = %s", GetSQLValueString($varPurchase_Datapurchase, "int"));
$Datapurchase = mysql_query($query_Datapurchase, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Datapurchase = mysql_fetch_assoc($Datapurchase);
$totalRows_Datapurchase = mysql_num_rows($Datapurchase);

$varTrolly_BookPurchase = "0";
if (isset($_GET["recordID"])) {
  $varTrolly_BookPurchase = $_GET["recordID"];
}
$varUser_BookPurchase = "0";
if (isset($row_Datapurchase['iduser'])) {
  $varUser_BookPurchase = $row_Datapurchase['iduser'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
$query_BookPurchase = sprintf("Select book.name, book.price From trolly inner join book on trolly.idbook = book.idbook where trolly.purchaseok = %s and trolly.iduser = %s", GetSQLValueString($varTrolly_BookPurchase, "int"),GetSQLValueString($varUser_BookPurchase, "int"));
$BookPurchase = mysql_query($query_BookPurchase, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_BookPurchase = mysql_fetch_assoc($BookPurchase);
$totalRows_BookPurchase = mysql_num_rows($BookPurchase);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/BaseAdmin.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Administration Book Store</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<link href="../style/twoColFixLtHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><img src="../images/logostore.png" width="275" height="183" alt="administration" />
    <!-- end .header --></div>
  <div class="sidebar1">
  <?php include("../includes/headadmin.php"); ?>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div class="content"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Content" -->
  <h1>User Purchase</h1>
  <p>Name: <?php echo $row_Datapurchase['iduser']; ?></p>

  <p>Date: <?php echo $row_Datapurchase['datepurchase']; ?></p>

  <p>Means of Payment: <?php echo $row_Datapurchase['typepayment']; ?></p>

  <p>Total: <?php echo $row_Datapurchase['total']; ?></p> 

  <p>Status of the actual purchase: <?php echo TextStatusPurchase($row_Datapurchase['status']); ?> </p>
  <p>Confirm Purchase</p>
  <p>Cancel Purchase</p>

  <p>Books:</p>

  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#009966">Book</td>
      <td bgcolor="#009966">Price</td>
      <td bgcolor="#009966">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr> 
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_BookPurchase['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_BookPurchase['price']; ?></td>

      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_BookPurchase = mysql_fetch_assoc($BookPurchase)); ?>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Administration Book Store</p>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Datapurchase);

mysql_free_result($BookPurchase);
?>
```

**Functions.php**

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

//*********************************************
//*********************************************
//**********************************************
function ObtainUserName($identifier)
{

  global $database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection;
    mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
    $query_QueryFunction = sprintf("SELECT user.name FROM user WHERE user.iduser = %s",$identifier);
    $QueryFunction = mysql_query($query_QueryFunction, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_QueryFunction = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryFunction);
    $totalRows_QueryFunction = mysql_num_rows($QueryFunction);

     return $row_QueryFunction['name']; 
    mysql_free_result($QueryFunction);
}
//*********************************************
//*********************************************
//**********************************************
function ObtainProductName($identifier)
{

  global $database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection;
    mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
    $query_QueryFunction = sprintf("SELECT name FROM book WHERE idbook = %s",$identifier);
    $QueryFunction = mysql_query($query_QueryFunction, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_QueryFunction = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryFunction);
    $totalRows_QueryFunction = mysql_num_rows($QueryFunction);

     return $row_QueryFunction['name']; 
    mysql_free_result($QueryFunction);
}
//*********************************************
//*********************************************
//**********************************************
function ObtainBookPrice($identifier)
{

  global $database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection;
    mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
    $query_QueryFunction = sprintf("SELECT price FROM book WHERE idbook = %s",$identifier);
    $QueryFunction = mysql_query($query_QueryFunction, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_QueryFunction = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryFunction);
    $totalRows_QueryFunction = mysql_num_rows($QueryFunction);

     return $row_QueryFunction['price']; 
    mysql_free_result($QueryFunction);
}
//*********************************************
//*********************************************
//**********************************************
function ObtainVAT()
{

  global $database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection;
    mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
    $query_QueryFunction = "SELECT vat FROM variables WHERE counter = 1";
    $QueryFunction = mysql_query($query_QueryFunction, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_QueryFunction = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryFunction);
    $totalRows_QueryFunction = mysql_num_rows($QueryFunction);

     return $row_QueryFunction['vat']; 
    mysql_free_result($QueryFunction);
}
//*********************************************
//*********************************************
//**********************************************


function trollyupdate($varpurchase)
{
     global $database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection;


    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE trolly SET purchaseok=%s WHERE iduser=%s AND purchaseok = 0",
                      $varpurchase,$_SESSION['MM_IdUser']);

  mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());

}

//*********************************************
//*********************************************
//**********************************************

function confirmpayment($typepayment)
{

  global $database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection;
    mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);

    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO purchase (iduser, datepurchase, typepayment, total) VALUES (%s, NOW(), %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['MM_IdUser'], "int"),
                       $typepayment,  
                       $_SESSION["Totalpurchase"]);

  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
  $lastpurchase = mysql_insert_id();
  trollyupdate($lastpurchase);

}
//*********************************************
//*********************************************
//**********************************************

function TextMeansPayment($varMeansPyament)
{
    if ($varMeansPyament == 1) return "Paypal";
    if ($varMeansPyament == 2) return "Transfer";

}

//*********************************************
//*********************************************
//**********************************************

function TextStatusPurchase($varstatus)
{
    if ($varstatus == 0) return "Waiting";
    if ($varstatus == 1) return "Pay and send";
    if ($varstatus == 2) return "Purchase cancel";

}


function Show_Trolly_User($identifier)
{

  global $database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection;
    mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
    $query_QueryFunction = sprintf("SELECT * FROM trolly WHERE purchaseok = %s",$identifier);
    $QueryFunction = mysql_query($query_QueryFunction, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_QueryFunction = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryFunction);
    $totalRows_QueryFunction = mysql_num_rows($QueryFunction);

    ?>
    <div class="subbooks">
    <?php

    do {
    echo ObtainProductName($row_QueryFunction['idbook']);
    echo "<br>"; 

    }while ($row_QueryFunction = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryFunction));

    ?>
    </div>
    <?php

    mysql_free_result($QueryFunction);
}
?>
```

Comment: did you include functions.php on purchase_edit.php ?

Comment: Also see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245854/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-tally

Comment: No i didnt... Where would i put include functions.php on my purchase_edit.php

Comment: try adding this at the top of purchase_edit.php: include_once('Functions.php'); and see if that helps. Note that this will work only when both of these php files are in the same directory.

Comment: Im still getting the fatal error...

Comment: are purchase_edit.php and Functions.php in same directory ? Can you update your code to reflect the changes that you made to the code ? If they are not in the same directory then you need to include the relative path to Functions.php.

Comment: They are not in the same directory. The purchase_edit.php is in a folder called admin... and the functions.php is in another folder called includes... I'm creating a site and i have different folders e.g admin, connections, includes, style, templates etc... The functions.php is in the includes folder and the purchase_edit.php is in the admin folder.

Comment: Then you need to include Functions.php relative to purchase_edit.php

Comment: Can you explain in simple forms how I would need to include Functions.php relative to purchase_edit.php.

Comment: Can you post your directory structure so that I can see where are the 2 files relative to each other ? Update your question with this information maybe ?

Comment: I have posted my directory structure... I hope that can help...

Comment: Try adding this at the top of purchase_edit.php: include_once ('includes/Functions.php') and see if that works.

Comment: Im getting an warning error: Warning: include_once(includes/Functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\bookstore\admin\cancel_purchase.php on line 1

Comment: did you not add that code to purchase_edit.php ?

Comment: It worked... But what I did was, i copied the functions.php and pasted in the same directory as the purchase_edit.php in the admin folder... Then i add <?php include_once ('functions.php') ?> at the top of the purchase_edit.php...

Comment: you shouldn't have to do that. If done correctly, the relative path approach should work fine too.